# Which category is A321-271NX in?

Tags: airbus-a320

I was wondering what the aircraft categories are all about because from my previous questions' answer I got to know about something called Cat D type aircraft. It made me curious to know what are the different types of aircraft categories and which one does the A321-271NX fall in, because it happens to be special for me!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code is for the exact variant for this Airbus:

- A321: This is an Airbus A321, the longest variant of the A320 family.
- 27*: It comes with PW1100 engines (which makes it a neo).
- 271: The exact engine variant, which can be found in the [TCDS (Type Certificate Data Sheet)](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/TCDS_EASA%20A%20064_%20Airbus_%20A318_A319_A320_A321_Iss_47.pdf):

  > PW1133G-JM Geared Turbo Fan jet engines (MOD 161002)
- N: Added for all neo variants.
- X: This means the aircraft has **Cabin Flex**, which allows the operator more freedom in choosing emergency exits:

  > these doors’ configuration flexibility are there to enable all customers’ operational needs without compromising on cabin comfort
  >
  > [image: Cabin Flex]

  <sup>([runwaygirlnetwork.com](https://runwaygirlnetwork.com/2016/08/18/airbus-explains-how-cabin-flex-enables-dense-a321neo-layouts/))</sup>

The "Cat D" you mentioned is the [approach speed categorisation](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Approach_Speed_Categorisation):

| Category | Approach Speed |
| --- | --- |
| A | < 91 kt |
| B | 91-120 kt |
| C | 121-140 kt |
| D | 141-165 kt |
| E | 166-210 kt |

The Airbus A321 can be in approach category C or D, depending on the exact variant:

> A321[ceo] has Approach Category C to 75.5 tonnes MLW and D beyond that to 77.8 tonnes.

<sup>([SKYbrary - Airbus A321](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/A321))</sup>

All A321neo aircraft are classified as Approach Category C:

> **ON A/C A321neo**
> [...]
> The final approach speed is 136 kt at a MLW of 79 200 kg (174 606 lb) and classifies the
> aircraft into the Aircraft Approach Category C.

<sup>([Airbus Aircraft Characteristics](https://www.airbus.com/en/airport-operations-and-technical-data/aircraft-characteristics) document AC A321 / A321neo)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your last afirmation is not correct, only for A321Ceo no A321 NEO.

All A321neo are CAT C. See section "Final Approach Speed" - AIRCRAFT CHARACTERISTICS - AIRPORT AND MAINTENANCE PLANNING

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Thanks for the correction, I updated my answer ;) In the future, you can also suggest such corrections as an edit to the original answer. Have a look at the [tour](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how the site works.