# A321 XLR or A321NXLR

Tags: airbus-neo

Wikipedia says that the A321XLR, will entering service in 2024,but when you look at Airfleets. net, TAP Portugal has already serval A321NXLR in use, or is this a different Model? how many Variants of the A321neo are there and what X stands for?

Answer (score 6):

The labels used on [airfleets.net](https://www.airfleets.net/flottecie/TAP%20Air%20Portugal-active-a321.htm) are indeed a bit confusing. Other sites write for [example](https://xfw-spotter.blogspot.com/2018/11/a321-251nx-tap-d-cs-txa-msn-8593.html) "A321-251NX/LR" to distinguish the "NX" from the "LR" part. Here is what everything means:

- **N** is added for all **neo** variants
- **X** refers to the **Cabin Flex** option that allows airlines to configure different emergency exits
- **LR** is the [**Long Range**](https://aircraft.airbus.com/en/aircraft/a320-the-most-successful-aircraft-family-ever/a321neo#routes) variant of the A321neo
- **XLR** is the [**Xtra Long Range**](https://aircraft.airbus.com/en/aircraft/a320/a321xlr) variant of the A321neo

So the TAP Air Portugal aircraft are A321 LR aircraft with cabin flex, not XLR. The XLR should enter service later this year (2024). I don't know how [airfleets.net](https://www.airfleets.net/flottecie/TAP%20Air%20Portugal-active-a321.htm) will show this variant, but it should probably be something like "NX/XLR".

More on Cabin Flex:

- From the [Airbus Newsroom](https://www.airbus.com/en/newsroom/press-releases/2018-07-airbus-delivers-the-first-a321neo-in-cabin-flex-configuration-to) in 2018:

  > The A321neo in Cabin Flex configuration is an option today and will become standard for all A321neos around 2020.
  >
  > The A321neo in Cabin Flex configuration is also the base for a longer range variant known as the A321LR.
- Related question: [Which category is A321-271NX in?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/84659/which-category-is-a321-271nx-in)